# Mate How to inject UI component

Tags: apache-flex, dependency-injection, mate

In the Mate framework for flex.  I'm trying to inject a UIComponent into a non UIComponent.

The reason is the UI component is a library component and it has methods that need to be invoked on it. I'm not able to remove the requirement to invoke the methods.

I've got something like this currently

```
<ObjectBuilder cache="global" generator="{DashboardController}" registerTarget="true"/>
<EventHandlers type="{DashboardEvent.DASHBOARD_CREATION_COMPLETE}">
    <PropertySetter generator="{DashboardController}" 
        targetKey="dashboard"
        source="{lastReturn}"
        sourceKey="target" />
</EventHandlers>
```

And I'm receiving an error like this.

```
---------------------------------------------------------
MATE Error: Property type mismatch, turn on the debugger for more information
EventType:test.example.events.creationComplete. Error was found in a EventHandlers list in file DashboardEventMap
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I've also tried using an object builder to set the property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the problem is your `lastReturn` type isn't compatible with `DashboardController.dashboard` field. Please recheck it.

Comment: Oh the last return is an event dispatched by an instance of Dashboard which contains that instance as the "target" property.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong it was returning null under some circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working. lastReturn was sometimes returning null even though it was in an eventHandling block.

I didn't realise that the event object was in scope here.

```
<EventHandlers type="{DashboardEvent.DASHBOARD_CREATION_COMPLETE}" debug="true">
    <PropertySetter generator="{DashboardController}" 
            targetKey="dashboard"
            source="{event.target}" />
</EventHandlers>
```